# Event in Angular Controller Only Fires Once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to implement an Angular version of an autocomplete textbox. I found some working examples, but none seem to exhibit the behavior I'm getting.

The autocomplete functionality itself works fine. When a suggested item is selected, the control correctly handles the selection. Subsequent uses of the control (typing in the autocomplete box, making a selection) fail to engage the 'selected' event/condition, although the autocomplete bit continues to work.

Here's my module & controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['angucomplete-alt']); //add angucomplete-alt dependency in app

app.controller('AutoCompleteController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

//reset users
$scope.Users = [];
$scope.SelectedUser = null;

//get data from the database
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/UserRoleAdministration/Autocomplete'
}).then(function (data) {
    $scope.Users = data.data;
}, function () {
    alert('Error');
})

//to fire when selection made
$scope.SelectedUser = function (selected) {
    if (selected) {
        $scope.SelectedUser = selected.originalObject;
    }
}

}]);
```

I'm guessing the problem is in there, but I don't know what it is. I include the bit from my view below, although there doesn't seem to be much there to fuss with:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="AutoCompleteController">
            <div angucomplete-alt id="txtAutocomplete" pause="0" selected-object="SelectedUser" local-data="Users" search-fields="RegularName" placeholder="People Search" title-field="RegularName" minlength="2" input-class="form-control" match-class="highlight"></div>
            <!--display selected user-->
            <br /><br />
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="panelResults">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Manage Roles for {{SelectedUser.RegularName}}</h3></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <img src="~/Images/avatar_blank.png" width="100%" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">Selected User:</div> <div class="col-md-6">{{SelectedUser.RegularName}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

## UPDATE

After fixing the mistake Yaser pointed out, I wasn't getting any information regarding the selected object. So I set the page to output the entire object, rather than the specified fields, and I noticed I *was* getting information about the selected object, and on subsequent attempts as well.

So this worked: {{SelectedUser}} 
This did not: {{SelectedUser.Department}}

Then I looked at the object and noticed its format. It had "title" and "description", and description had inside **it** the key/value pairs.

So now this works: {{SelectedUser.description.Department}}

And that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first time you are setting $scope.SelectedUser as a function but inside that you are rewriting the same one with an object. so next time it is not a function any more, try to rename the function:

```
$scope.setUser = function (selected) {
    if (selected) {
        $scope.SelectedUser = selected.originalObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it makes sense. But now when I run it, the selected user isn't displayed at all.

Comment: Edited my question with my resolution, which relied on your answer. Thanks!